# After executing suite file of Slim type Fitnesse is not getting stopped

Tags: fitnesse

I have created many suite files using SLIM type but after running all the testcases/suites that Fitnesse is not getting stopped it is keep on running  but in FIT type it is working fine only.
Kindly anybody give me suggestions on this how we can make it stop automatically after completion of suite file.Actually it should get stop after execution is over.

Regards,
PradeepKumar

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that there is an object that needed to be closed out or destroyed?  It has been seen with Selenium that if you don't close out the driver that it can cause tests to hang at the end. So in our case we had to have

```
driver.quit();
```

Triggered by some sort of suite tear down.

Slim doesn't want to force the destruction, as there is still an active reference.

Comment: In latest standalone version it is getting stopped but in console am seeing some exception as process failed but my all the suite file is executing properly.Can anyone give me what is the problem and how to resolve that pls ?

Comment: Can you provide any more details about the fixtures that you are using? What are they doing and what do they talk to?